# echache3 XML parsing issue

Tags: xml, ehcache-3

For some reason, I can't add the expiry element into the ehcache3 configuration xml.
without the expiry element, it works fine.

```
  <config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>

  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults>
      <jsr107:cache name="people" template="heap-cache"/>
    </jsr107:defaults>
  </service>

  <cache-template name="heap-cache">
    <listeners>
        <listener>
          <class>org.terracotta.ehcache.EventLogger</class>
          <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
          <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
          <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
          <events-to-fire-on>UPDATED</events-to-fire-on>
          <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
          <events-to-fire-on>REMOVED</events-to-fire-on>
          <events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
     <expiry>
        <ttl unit="seconds">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <resources>
      <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
      <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap> <!-- unit of measure is case sensitive! -->
    </resources>
  </cache-template>
</config>
```

the error message is:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'expiry'. One of '{"http://www.ehcache.org/v3":heap, "http://www.ehcache.org/v3":resources, "http://www.ehcache.org/v3":heap-store-settings, "http://www.ehcache.org/v3":disk-store-settings, "http://www.ehcache.org/v3":service-configuration}' is expected.
```

but looking at this xsd:
http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core.xsd
I don't see anything wrong the tag, anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ehcache 3 strictly enforces the XSD, so the elements inside a `cache` or `cache-template` must be in the following order:

1. `key-type`
2. `value-type`
3. `expiry`
4. `eviction-advisor`
5. `loader-writer`
6. `listeners`
7. `resources` OR `heap`
8. more ...

with all elements being optional aside from the sizing (place 7) which is optional in a `cache-template` though.

Answer (score 2):

You must add `xsi:schemaLocation` and `listeners` config after `expiry`

Correct form of your ehcache config is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

    <service>
        <jsr107:defaults>
            <jsr107:cache name="people" template="heap-cache"/>
        </jsr107:defaults>
    </service>

    <!--thread-pools> 
        <thread-pool alias="defaultDiskPool" min-size="1" max-size="3"/>
    </thread-pools-->

    <!--disk-store thread-pool="defaultDiskPool" /-->

    <cache-template name="heap-cache">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">10</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <listeners>
            <listener>
                <class>org.terracotta.ehcache.EventLogger</class>
                <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
                <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
                <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>UPDATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>REMOVED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on>
            </listener>
        </listeners>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap> <!-- unit of measure is case sensitive! -->
        </resources>

        <!--disk-store-settings thread-pool="defaultDiskPool" writer-concurrency="2" /-->

    </cache-template>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the format/example that worked for me (I took it from the [ehcache docs](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.7/examples.html#xml-with-107-extension)):

```
<ehcache:config xmlns:ehcache="http://www.ehcache.org/v3" xmlns:jcache="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107">
    <ehcache:cache alias="books">
        <ehcache:key-type>java.lang.String</ehcache:key-type>
        <ehcache:value-type>hello.Book</ehcache:value-type>
        <ehcache:resources>
            <ehcache:heap unit="MB">1</ehcache:heap>
            <!--ehcache:offheap unit="MB">10</ehcache:offheap-->
        </ehcache:resources>
    </ehcache:cache>
</ehcache:config>
```